# reading integers from text file in c

Tags: c, file-io, input, fgets

I want to read a text file where image pixels values are stored in this fashion

```
234
23
176
235
107
187
201
128
147
...
....
..
```

I tried to read this text file in this manner

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define M 2500
int main()
{

unsigned  new_img[M];
unsigned char a;
FILE *input;
input=fopen("D:/trail.txt","r");
for(i=0;i<M;i++)
{
    a=fgetc(input);
    new_img[i]=(int)a; 
    input++;
}
....

....

...
return 0;
}
```

when I tried it to print it showing some random values.
Also, all my pixels values are in the range of 0 to 255. But at the output screen I am getting values as large as 1 to 1 million

Comment: fgetc reads a character, not an integer.

Comment: Replace everything in your `for` loop with `fscanf("%d",&new_img[i]);`. Checking if the return value of `fscanf` is 1 is also good

Comment: [Lakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) meaning 100,000 is not common in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) of `fgetc()`, we can see

> fgetc() reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.

it reads *character-by-character* in lexicographical way, not based on the *value*.

Instead I suggest

- read a line using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
- convert the *string* input to `int` using [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)
- store it into the array.

Some other suggestions:

1. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. Always check for the success of `fopen()` before using the returned pointer.
3. FWIW, `fgetc()` returns an `int`. You should collect the return value in an `int` variable, ideally.

<sub>Note: you need to take care of the trailing `\n` read by `fgets()` and error checking for the validity of input.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`fgetc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc), which is not the right way to read integers, and also doing it wrong. Notice that its return type is `int`, since it can return the constant `EOF`. You're truncating the return value into an `unsigned char`, which makes no sense.

It reads *characters*, so for an input string of e.g. `234`, you would first see the character `2`, then `3`, then `4`, then the line feed character(s), and so on. Not what you want.

You should just use:

```
int pixel;

if(fscanf(input, "%d", &pixel) == 1)
{
  printf("read pixel %d\n", pixel);
}
```

This converts a decimal integer (which can consist of many individual characters), and writes the integer into `pixel`. If it fails, it won't return `1`.